# Where is 'tsrm_ls' in PHP sources?

Tags: php

I'm coding an extension to change the way PHP handles errors. Where is '**tsrm_ls**' declared? I can't find it.

**P.S.** I think it is a 'typedef'

**Edit:** Still can't find it. Is it declared locally? I think it is used in the *EG* macro.

Comment: lol can't you use just set_error_handler?

Comment: I need to catch fatal and parse errors.

Comment: I am just wandering why you'll need to do that? I believe there is another solution then writing your own extension which you have to maintenance when upgrading your php version. Thanks.

Comment: I'm obsessed with error depictions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
TSRMLS_FETCH();
```

Have to run it before calling any of those macros.

Answer (score 4):

You might find this explanation quite helpful:
http://blog.golemon.com/2006/06/what-heck-is-tsrmlscc-anyway.html

Answer (score 1):

http://lxr.php.net/search?q=tsrm_ls&project=PHP_5_3&defs=&refs=&path=&hist=

Comment: Still can't find it. It is used in a macro.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather it might be in php_apache.c